# how to add smilies/emotions in my edittext for a notes app in android?

Tags: android, png, android-edittext, notepad

can any one know about how to add/insert emotions/smiles to text(which ever i typed in my edit text for my notes). i have little confusion about if i want to add these smiles of type .png in to edit text type of string, is it possible? and also i have to save these input into sqlite database. normally i know to store string data taken from edit text.
but along with that text i want to also add smiles symbols where ever my cursor placed and to be store in sqlite data base. and get it back to read.
so guys any ideas, most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use java (i.e. android) spannable method to implement smiley (i.e.) images for that. You will surely get it, search in google for "how to add images/smiley with java spannable method in android?" you will get good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question the first thing I can think of is Mapping each image to a sequence of letters, for example :) is smiley.png etc. Now your database also has these smaller representation However while reading from the database you can convert those special character sequences to appropriate image.

For simplicity in seraching those Strings You can wrap them in some less used characters i.e. [ or { or <.

Comment: if i open the smilies list and select one smilies symbol,cant it placed in edit text?